# How do I include a valid regular line instruction before a literal block in YAML?

Tags: yaml

If I use the pipe delimiter to add a literal block to my yml file like so, this is valid YAML:

```yaml
build: 
     |
     if [ <condition> ]; then
          <command>
     else
          <command>
     fi 
     
     - mv file-a file-b
```

But if I need the block to follow after some other regular instructions, it's invalid and the code won't run as expected:

```yaml
build: 
     - mv file-a file-b 

     |
     if [ <condition> ]; then
          <command>
     else
          <command>
     fi
```

Why is this the case, and what am I doing wrong? I definitely need the regular instructions to come first before the block.

The regular single line commands should be evaluated without error and then proceed to the literal block instructions. But the code is invalid and doesn't work. It only works if I place the literal block first in order.

"It looks like your post is mostly code". Honestly there's nothing else to say.

Okay, would you like me to tell you a story? This site isn't the same as it used to be.

Comment: YAML is a data serialization language. It doesn't *evaluate* anything, particularly not shell commands. We can help you with YAML *syntax*, but if you want help with *semantics*, you need to tell us the schema of your YAML file, i.e. which tool is processing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal block scalar continues until it encounters a line that is less indented than the block scalar. That is to say, in your first example, the line

```
- mv file-a file-b
```

is processed as part of the block scalar.

However, in your second example, you place this line in front of the block scalar, which makes it a block sequence item. Block sequence items can exist on the same level only with other block sequence items. A literal block scalar is not a block sequence item, hence it cannot be on the same level.

You can make the literal scalar a block sequence item:

```yaml
build: 
    - mv file-a file-b 
    - |
      if [ <condition> ]; then
          <command>
      else
          <command>
      fi
```

Or you simply make the command part of the literal block scalar:

```yaml
build: |
    mv file-a file-b 
    if [ <condition> ]; then
        <command>
    else
        <command>
    fi
```

It is unclear from your description what you intend the structure to be, but one of these solutions is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I stumbled onto your second solution ("make command part of the literal block scalar") accidentally when 'trying things' and it worked, so your answer is correct and I hope it helps someone else in the future.